# Why does the breakpoints changes the expected behavior of the code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I am using `setInterval()` to wait for DOM element to load that is `div.product_box`.

Once the DOM element is loaded, the application will execute API Calls for the number of items available. whenever a response for an item is received, the progress bar in the image below should increment.

When I use breakpoints and track the code step-by-step, the loader works as expected (as shown in the image below)
[image: With breakpoints]

However, when I run the project without breakpoints, the progress bar doesn't move (as shown in the below picture):

[image: without breakpoints]

Below is the code responsible for updating the progress bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
        if ($('div.product_box').length) {
            let percentageToIncrease = (100/$('div.product_box').length).toFixed();
            let tempStorage = 0;
            $('div.product_box').each(function(e) {
                percentageToIncrease = parseInt(percentageToIncrease);
                        tempStorage = parseInt(tempStorage);
                        $('#progressBar').width(tempStorage + percentageToIncrease + '%')
                        $('#progressBar').text(tempStorage + percentageToIncrease + '%');
                        tempStorage = tempStorage + percentageToIncrease;
                let myArray = this.innerHTML.split("text-muted\">");
                myArray = myArray[1].split('\n');
                const productName = myArray[0];

                pos_product_row($(this).data('variation_id'), productName)
                if($('div.product_box').length == (e+1)){
                    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                    $('#exampleModalLong').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        }
       }, 100);
});
```

and here is the progress bar in the `HTML` :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Uploading your files</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        It won't take a while
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
The API call is executed for each item is below (the code before the `ajax` call is to configure the variables to be sent in the API call):

```
function pos_product_row(variation_id = null, productName = '', purchase_line_id = null, weighing_scale_barcode = null, quantity = 1) {

    //Get item addition method
    var item_addtn_method = 0;
    var add_via_ajax = true;

    if (variation_id != null && $('#item_addition_method').length) {
        item_addtn_method = $('#item_addition_method').val();
    }

    if (item_addtn_method == 0) {
        add_via_ajax = true;
    } else {
        var is_added = false;
        //Search for variation id in each row of pos table
        $('#pos_table tbody')
            .find('tr')
            .each(function() {
                var row_v_id = $(this)
                    .find('.row_variation_id')
                    .val();
                var enable_sr_no = $(this)
                    .find('.enable_sr_no')
                    .val();
                var modifiers_exist = false;
                if ($(this).find('input.modifiers_exist').length > 0) {
                    modifiers_exist = true;
                }

                if (
                    row_v_id == variation_id &&
                    enable_sr_no !== '1' &&
                    !modifiers_exist &&
                    !is_added
                ) {
                    add_via_ajax = false;
                    is_added = true;

                    //Increment product quantity
                    qty_element = $(this).find('.pos_quantity');
                    var qty = __read_number(qty_element);
                    __write_number(qty_element, qty + 1);
                    qty_element.change();

                    round_row_to_iraqi_dinnar($(this));

                    $('input#search_product')
                        .focus()
                        .select();
                }
        });
    }

    if (add_via_ajax) {
        var product_row = $('input#product_row_count').val();
        var location_id = $('input#location_id').val();
        var customer_id = $('select#customer_id').val();

        var is_direct_sell = false;
        if (
            $('input[name="is_direct_sale"]').length > 0 &&
            $('input[name="is_direct_sale"]').val() == 1
        ) {
            is_direct_sell = true;
        }

        var is_sales_order = $('#sale_type').length && $('#sale_type').val() == 'sales_order' ? true : false;

        var price_group = '';
        if ($('#price_group').length > 0) {
            price_group = parseInt($('#price_group').val());
        }

        //If default price group present
        if ($('#default_price_group').length > 0 && 
            price_group === '') {
            price_group = $('#default_price_group').val();
        }

        //If types of service selected give more priority
        if ($('#types_of_service_price_group').length > 0 && 
            $('#types_of_service_price_group').val()) {
            price_group = $('#types_of_service_price_group').val();
        }
        
        if(localStorage.getItem(productName)){
            let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(productName));

             $('table#pos_table tbody')
                        .append(result.html_content)
                        .find('input.pos_quantity');
                    //increment row count
                    $('input#product_row_count').val(parseInt(product_row) + 1);
                    var this_row = $('table#pos_table tbody')
                        .find('tr')
                        .last();
                    pos_each_row(this_row);

                    //For initial discount if present
                    var line_total = __read_number(this_row.find('input.pos_line_total'));
                    this_row.find('span.pos_line_total_text').text(line_total);

                    pos_total_row();

                    //Check if multipler is present then multiply it when a new row is added.
                    if(__getUnitMultiplier(this_row) > 1){
                        this_row.find('select.sub_unit').trigger('change');
                    }

                    if (result.enable_sr_no == '1') {
                        var new_row = $('table#pos_table tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .last();
                        new_row.find('.row_edit_product_price_model').modal('show');
                    }

                    round_row_to_iraqi_dinnar(this_row);
                    __currency_convert_recursively(this_row);

                    $('input#search_product')
                        .focus()
                        .select();

                    //Used in restaurant module
                    if (result.html_modifier) {
                        $('table#pos_table tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .last()
                            .find('td:first')
                            .append(result.html_modifier);
                    }

                    //scroll bottom of items list
                    $(".pos_product_div").animate({ scrollTop: $('.pos_product_div').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
            
        } else if(navigator.onLine){
            $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/sells/pos/get_product_row/' + variation_id + '/' + location_id,
            async: false,
            data: {
                product_row: product_row,
                customer_id: customer_id,
                is_direct_sell: is_direct_sell,
                price_group: price_group,
                purchase_line_id: purchase_line_id,
                weighing_scale_barcode: weighing_scale_barcode,
                quantity: quantity,
                is_sales_order: is_sales_order
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    
                    let myArray = result.html_content.split("myModalLabel\">");
                    myArray = myArray[1].split(' -');
                    const productFinalName = myArray[0];

                    $('table#pos_table tbody')
                        .append(result.html_content)
                        .find('input.pos_quantity');
                    //increment row count
                    $('input#product_row_count').val(parseInt(product_row) + 1);
                    var this_row = $('table#pos_table tbody')
                        .find('tr')
                        .last();
                    pos_each_row(this_row);

                    //For initial discount if present
                    var line_total = __read_number(this_row.find('input.pos_line_total'));
                    this_row.find('span.pos_line_total_text').text(line_total);

                    pos_total_row();

                    //Check if multipler is present then multiply it when a new row is added.
                    if(__getUnitMultiplier(this_row) > 1){
                        this_row.find('select.sub_unit').trigger('change');
                    }

                    if (result.enable_sr_no == '1') {
                        var new_row = $('table#pos_table tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .last();
                        new_row.find('.row_edit_product_price_model').modal('show');
                    }

                    round_row_to_iraqi_dinnar(this_row);
                    __currency_convert_recursively(this_row);

                    $('input#search_product')
                        .focus()
                        .select();

                    //Used in restaurant module
                    if (result.html_modifier) {
                        $('table#pos_table tbody')
                            .find('tr')
                            .last()
                            .find('td:first')
                            .append(result.html_modifier);
                    }
                    //scroll bottom of items list
                    $(".pos_product_div").animate({ scrollTop: $('.pos_product_div').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
                    if(productName != null){
                        localStorage.setItem(productName, JSON.stringify(result))
                    } else {
                        localStorage.setItem(productFinalName, JSON.stringify(result))
                    }

                } else {
                    toastr.error(result.msg);
                    $('input#search_product')
                        .focus()
                        .select();
                }
            },
        });
        }
        
    }
}
```

What is causing the progress bar to behave differently with and without the breakpoints?

Comment: I would assume the breakpoints are allowing time for the API calls to complete.  Where are your API calls?

Comment: @James I have updated the question with the API call

Comment: You can observe the DOM through a MutationObserver to verify dom changes.